# Invalid cross reference Id when I'm querying fullName of a CustomField using Tooling SOAP API

Tags: custom-field, query, tooling-api

I'm trying to get a **fullName** field of a **CustomObject** in query

`QueryResult queryResult =
      toolingConnection.query("select TableEnumOrId, FullName, LastModifiedDate from CustomField " );`

I have two developer edition accounts. In the first it works, in the second I get **Invalid cross reference id**.  When I remove **fullName** from query, it works.

The code is absolutely the same in both cases, I change only credentials.

Here is the full error message:

`[UnexpectedErrorFault [ApiFault  exceptionCode='INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY'
 exceptionMessage='invalid cross reference id'
 upgradeURL='null'
 upgradeMessage='null'
]
]`

What could be the reason?

And what does this exception generally mean?

Comment: Can you provide more details of the error (full message) as well as more context around the code? I do not see in your code where you are setting or filtering by ID. The error means you are setting or filtering by an ID that is not an ID of the object type you are querying / filtering on

Comment: I've just updated my question and now it contains full error message. The problem is that I'm NOT setting or filtering by ID. I've provided the full text of my query  (I did copy-paste). Before that call the only thing I do is create **toolingConnection**.

Comment: Stumped as the definition of the error is: "An invalid foreign key can't be set on a field. For example, if an object share such as AccountShare can't be deleted because the share row is a result of a sharing rule" So if you are not setting an ID then there should be no reason to throw the error. Are you sure the error occurs due to that query? Also, what enviroment are you developing in?

Comment: I am curious if the application is adding to the query you posted. Typically you see a space after the last part of the query like you have - CustomField " - when there is a concatenation going to happen

Comment: I'm developing in the Developer Edition environment, Java. Yes, I'm sure because 1) the same line of code works when I remove **fullName** 2) the same line of code works when I login to the other Developer Edition account. You can see that space because the **where** clause is supposed to be (I would like to do "where lastModifiedDate > ...") but I removed this part when I found out that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I believe I have found the cause:

When it hits a field with __del it provides the error

Data_Quality_Description_del

caused the error

Although I have other field that came in the query with the _del suffix I think it may be because the field AND the object were both deleted?

Although when I was able to reproduce the error, I cannot say for sure what caused it because I cannot find the field in the org.

I would still open a case with Salesforce to see if they can resolve the issue because it is a BUG

Comment: Yes,  it could be, because the first one is **emea** and the second one is **eu2** if I'm not mistaking. So it seems that I have to omit query fullName(

Comment: I know about `developerName` field but I need to get a name of a SObject that contains modified field. I know also about the field `TableEnumOrId` but in that case I need to distinguish `ID` and `Enum` somehow. I thought that `ID` can have only digit at the first position but it seems that it doesn't

Comment: Oh I think you are right. I was trying to trace my deleted fields using that query( Thank you!

Comment: > I would still open a case with Salesforce to see if they can resolve the issue because it is a BUG. - I can't do this, I have only Developer Edition Account